# How to use For Loop to add integer as a string in list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have created the list below:

```
Stores = ['Costco','Publix', 'Kroger', 'Target']
```

I am asked to create a another list (Store_Rank) to define their ranking by adding integers in front. However, the integers should be in a list format.

I am assuming f-interpolation is to be used?

"Store_Rank" list should output the following:

```
1. Costco, 2. Publix, 3. Kroger, 4. Target
```

Note>>> Expected result is to have

```
  Store_Rank [0] = 1. Costco

  Store_Rank[2] =  2. Publix
```

etc..

Please Help!

Comment: Are you missing a bunch of quotation marks in your code? `[Costco, Publix, ...]` is a list build from variable names, but do you actually mean `["Costco", "Publix", ...]`?

Comment: Good Catch. I will add the quotation marks

Comment: @Kadodo14, I just added an answer to your question, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code:

```
Stores = [Costco, Publix, Kroger, Target]
Store_rank = []
for i in range(0, len(Stores)):
    Store_rank.append(str(i+1) + ". " + Stores[i])
```

Comment: It is usually preferable to use `enumerate` rather than iterate through the indices. Also, you might want to use format strings rather than concatenation, though both methods are fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean! I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Question on Store_rank = []. Are you defining it as an empty list? Any reason why? Thanks in advance

Comment: That if you rerun the codeblock e.g. in jupyter notebooks the list gets emptied again and not everything is appended another time

Answer (score 1):

Short code using `enumerate`

```
Store_Rank = [str(idx) + ". " + store for idx, store in enumerate(Stores, start=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can use a list comprehension and f-strings as follows:

```
>>> Stores = ['Costco','Publix', 'Kroger', 'Target']
>>> [f'{i}. {store}' for i, store in enumerate(Stores, start=1)]
['1. Costco', '2. Publix', '3. Kroger', '4. Target']
```